# puppet need to call file resource from exec resource only

Tags: puppet

Is there anyway to call puppet `file` resource from `exec` resource only when `unless` condition met? Means by default `file` resource shouldn't executed and it can be triggered thru exec resource only.

Updated details:

Here is my manifest file

```
file { '/tmp/test_script.sh':
        path => '/tmp/test_script.sh',
        mode => 755,
        owner => 'root',
        group => 'root',
        ensure => file,
        source => "puppet:///modules/custom_files//tmp/test_script.sh",
}

exec {'run_script':
        unless => '/bin/rpm -qa | grep package-name',
        require => File['test_script.sh'],
        command => '/tmp/test_script.sh',
}
```

Here I want `file { '/tmp/test_script.sh':` resource has to executed only when condition `unless => '/bin/rpm -qa | grep package-name',` on exec resource doesn't meet. Otherwise this file resource shouldn't be executed.

Comment: why do you need such thing?

Comment: No, there isn't.  If you explain more fully what you're trying to accomplish, then maybe we can suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: I agree with @JohnBollinger, i'm not sure that you have provided enough information for anyone to give you an educated opinion an an alternate approach. Can you provide a code example?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Updated the details in primary query itself. Can you please provide some lights..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you present has no chance of working anything like how you intend.  Because the `Exec` requires the `File` to (conditionally) be applied first, its own `unless` parameter would not be evaluated in time to affect that, even if there were a way it could do.

Generally speaking, details of machines' current state on which Puppet is to base decisions about the contents of that machine's catalog must be communicated to the catalog compiler via *facts*.  Puppet / Facter has no built-in fact that conveys the information you need, but it is pretty easy to add an [external fact](https://docs.puppet.com/facter/3.3/custom_facts.html#external-facts) or a [custom fact](https://docs.puppet.com/facter/3.3/fact_overview.html) that the agent will evaluate for you.

Details vary slightly according to the software versions involved, but if you are using even remotely recent Puppet and Facter then my recommendation would be an external fact.  For example, you might drop this script in the appropriate module's `facts.d/` directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo mypackage=$(/bin/rpm -q mypackage || echo none)
```

In your manifest, you could then do this:

```
if $mypackage == 'none' {
  file { '/tmp/test_script.sh':
    path   => '/tmp/test_script.sh',
    mode   => 755,
    owner  => 'root',
    group  => 'root',
    ensure => file,
    source => "puppet:///modules/custom_files//tmp/test_script.sh",
  }

  exec {'run_script':
    command => '/tmp/test_script.sh',
    require => File['test_script.sh'],
  }
}
```

Note that facts are evaluated before any resources are applied, so if you have other manifests that might manage the RPM in question, then you'll want to coordinate with that.

Comment: Thanks for detailed information! It helps me out thru facts. I thought same way should be there in puppet file resource itself to restrict this.